# What monitor size and resolution for analyzing Lidar data

Tags: monitors

I have just started a PhD for which I will also analyze LIDAR data. Our IT guy has asked me what kind of monitor I would like, with the following options:

24 inch Full HD + small SD monitor.

27 inch Full HD.

27 inch 2540x1440 monitor.

The laptop I'll be using this with is a Lenovo T470P with i7-7770HQ and 16 GB RAM.

Do you guys think it will be worth it to have the higher resolution monitor for my LIDAR data or is it not necessary and would a Full HD monitor by sufficient as well?

I don't want him to spend all his budget on me if it is not necessary. On the other hand, I also don't want to be limited by my monitor in my analysis, and this is more important for me.

I will be plotting points on the LIDAR imagery and might also do some arcgis tasks, although at this point it is difficult to state what exactly I will be doing (just started this week and have mostly been doing admin). An important point to note is that I can use my laptop as a second monitor and so the extra SD monitor would be the third monitor.

Comment: Part of the question should be what kinds of activities do you think you will be doing as a part of the task of analyzing Lidar data. Please update your post with those tasks. I would assume that there will be visual representations through imagery large screen and high resolution count however I am also wondering if there would be need for display of text as well. And will there be a need for interacting with the imagery by plotting points and that sort of thing? It may well be that having two displays, one for imagery and one for software tools would be the best alternative.

Comment: I've updated the info. This is more or less what I thought myself as well, thank you for the reply!

Comment: I am not sure how useful a third monitor would be nor what is the size and resolution of a "small SD monitor". I would be inclined to go with the 27 inch 2540x1440 though the question may also be whether your laptop GPU can drive that to its native resolution or not. And you would need to match up display inputs (DVi, HDMI, etc.) with what the laptop has connections for. You may need an adapter if the laptop only does HDMI [HDMI with resolution 2560 x 1440 possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible)